# using both initializer_list and vector constructor

Tags: c++

I want to be able to initialize an object Box with both Box b{1,2,3} as well as a provided vector (std::vector v{1,2,3}; Box b{v}).
So I created two constructors (see below), one taking a vector of integers - nothing fancy here, it just initializes the member variable m_obj with the provided vector. The other one with an initializer list.

```
class Box{
public:
    std::vector<int> m_obj;
    explicit Box(const std::vector<int> v) : m_obj{v} {}
    explicit Box(const std::initializer_list<int>& ls) {
        for(int i: ls) m_obj.push_back(i);
    }
    ~Box() {}
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
    Box b2{v};
}
```

So far so good. However my actual object Box contains a vector of another custom Object (Obj) which can be both initialized with an integer as well as a double. So I template my constructor:

```
template <typename T>
explicit Box(const std::initializer_list<T>& ls) {
    for(const T& e: ls)
        m_obj.push_back(e);
    }
```

relying on that push_back(arg) will construct the Obj and push it (Obj constructors are not explicit).
However already without the added Obj the code now starts breaking - although the main() part was not changed.

```
main.cpp:15:19: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
            m_obj.push_back(e);
```

It seems even though I'm providing a vector the compiler is still trying to use the initializer_list constructor. Can someone make sense of what's going on/wrong here?

For completeness, here's a complete version that will reproduce the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class Obj{
public:
    Obj(int) {std::cout << "int constructor\n";}
    Obj(double) {std::cout << "double constructor\n";}
    ~Obj() {}
};

class Box{
public:
    std::vector<Obj> m_obj;
    explicit Box(const std::vector<Obj> v) : m_obj{v} {}
    template <typename T>
    explicit Box(const std::initializer_list<T>& ls) {
        for(const T& e: ls)
            m_obj.push_back(e);
    }
    ~Box() {}
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
    Box b1{ 1, 2 };
    Box b2{ 1.1, 2.2 };
    // Box b3{v};        // produces mentioned error
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre], in particular the definition of `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an object that is conceptually a sequence of objects which can be initialized with a sequence of objects via initializer-list syntax (ie: `{}`) *only use* initializer-list syntax when you are *specifically* initializing it with a sequence of objects.

`Box b2{v};` is not *intended* to  initalizing `Box` from an initializer-list of objects. You intend to *convert* a `v` into a `Box`. Therefore, use constructor syntax: `Box b2(v);`

`initializer_list` constructors are given priority when using initializer-list syntax. `{v}` means "initialize with a sequence of objects consisting of one object of type `v` if at all possible". Since your initializer_list constructor is an unconstrained template that can take any sequence of any length, it will deduce *any* `{X}` as calling itself. It does this in this case by deducing `T` as `vector<int>`, since that's the type of `v`.

`vector<int>` is not convertible to an `int`, which is why `push_back` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initializer_lists but use a template constructor like this :

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class Box
{
public:
    explicit Box(const std::vector<int>& v) : 
        m_values{v} 
    {
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    explicit Box(const int (&values)[N]) :
        m_values{std::begin(values), std::end(values)}
    {
    }

    ~Box() {}


private:
    std::vector<int> m_values;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2};
    Box b2{v};
    Box b3{{1,2,3}};
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass `{1,2,3}` to an `const int (*values)[N]`.  Fascinating.

Comment: Note I changed from pointer to const &, but yes I use it all the time, somehow I really don't like initializer lists. I also do it for compile time constant strings (mind that you get an extra trailing zero in the array too)